# When you care but don't act on it to make it right

Tags: single-word-requests

For example people genuinely care about homeless people but most don't do anything to try and make a difference, is there a word to describe this?

Comment: Hypocrisy. Doesn't sound like they actually genuinely care.

Comment: Armchair activist.

Comment: **Ineffectual** fits in here somewhere, but I don't think it rises to the level of an answer: http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ineffectual

Answer (score 1):

This is a major problem for political and social activists: Getting people who believe in whatever cause to actually do something about it.  It's not *yet* a widely accepted term, but at least the [Urban Dictionary recognizes **inactivist**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=inactivist) as the word you're looking for.  It has a nice symmetry:  For example, "peace activists" believe in peace and take actions to further the cause.  "Peace *inactivists*" believe but are inactive in the cause.

Another term that avoids the ad hominem connotation of words like "lazy" is "uncommitted."  E.g., "I'm an uncommitted vegan."

Answer (score 0):

I know this may sound prosaic, but "inactive" seems fitting. "Idle" also could work. The word you're looking for partly depends on the speaker's attitude toward the inaction. For example, is the speaker of the sentence critical of the person who does nothing to make a difference?

If the speaker is especially critical or positive, the word choice may even distort the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Commenter @curiousdannii is correct, of course, at least regarding some folks. They--we--can become hypocritical with very little effort. Reminds me of a Peanuts cartoon (thanks to Charles Schulz) in which one of the characters said,

> "I love mankind. It's people I can't stand."

A better descriptor which comes to my mind is **ambivalence**, a state of emotional confusion in which two or more emotions and/or conflicting thoughts create a bit of dissonance within us.

A person whose heart genuinely goes out to homeless people but is afraid to get involved because his or her involvement might get "messy" is perhaps experiencing ambivalence.

To sympathize in the abstract with people who are less fortunate than us is relatively easy, I suggest, but to empathize truly with a flesh-and-blood human being whom we can see and touch and smell(!) is not so easy. Not that everyone has to get down and dirty with folks who are dirty and down.

Sometimes simply writing a generous check to a local homeless shelter is a perfectly fine and admirable thing to do. Politicians, too, are to be commended when they draw attention to the plight of the homeless in their sphere of influence, even though they may never step inside a homeless shelter or visit a camp of homeless people who live, eat, and sleep just six blocks from his or her office!

In conclusion, not everyone is "called" to serve "the last, the least, and the lost," but one need not be "called" to offer to invite a homeless person to a fast-food restaurant and treat him or her to a meal and a little conversation, face to face. Who knows what might become of that first tentative step toward getting to know another human being. Yes, things can get messy, but hey, life is messy.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that such a **[passive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/passive)** supporter is hypocritical or at least paradoxical. The choice of the term depends on the underlying reasons you ascribe to such behaviour, but you might use these adjectives:

**[lackadaisical](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lackadaisical)**:

> Lacking enthusiasm and determination;
>
> *The President is remarkably lackadaisical about finding the senior administration official who leaked the identity of a CIA operative.* (ODO)

**[supine](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/supine)**:

> Failing to act or protest as a result of moral weakness or indolence:
>
> *the government was supine in the face of racial injustice* (ODO)